# Does EC2 need Xen kernel?

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos6, centos5, kernel, amazon-ami

I am on to creating a new AMI image for CentOS 6.4. Until now I was on CentOS 5.6. I started with the CentOS market place image, and what I noticed is that it is running a regular kernel and not xen kernel, unlike my CentOS 5.6 image.

I am trying to answer following questions to my self.
 - Does EC2 need a xen-enabled kernel at all? Some of the AWS document I read says that run your own kernel using pvgrub. But my assumptions was that even if I boot using pvgrub, I need xen enabled kernel?
 - Does CentOS 6.4 kernel, kernel-2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64, is compiled with xen functionality?
 - Or pvgrub is doing some magic? I really doubt this, because as far as I understand pvgrub will boot the actual kernel image and handover control to main kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if EC2 normally required a Xen kernel, but what I can tell you is that kernels from 2.6.32 include pv_ops, which makes them run on any virtualized environment.

Comment: Thanks I think that answers the question. http://www.slideshare.net/xen_com_mgr/the-sexy-world-of-linux-kernel-pvops-project The 4th slide in this presentation is precisely the answer. "Solves the early problem of classic Xen kernels: a distribution needed to ship two kernels: one for native, one for Xen.● Pvops extensions solved the problem - it allows the Linux kernel during runtime to figure out if it is running under any virtualization stacks (Xen, KVM) and swap over to using optimized low-level operations for the specific virtualization stack."